# How do I subset and manipulate time series data with lubridate and dplyr in Rstudio?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have loaded in time series data of creek depth and am needing to calculate total annual values (Oct-April) for each year. The following is what I have tried thus far:

```
depth <- read_csv("Depth.Water_Depth-_All_Instruments@GCNP_-_Robber's_Roost_Spring.EntireRecord .csv")
```

The following is a screenshot of the resulting data frame
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqXzZ.png)

These are my attempts at making the timestamp column (ISO_UTC) into a date class. Although, each attempt makes all values for ISO_UTC into N/A values instead of dates / times.

```
ymd_hm(depth$ISO_UTC)

depth$ISO_UTC<- as.Date(depth$ISO_UTC, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")

depth$ISO_UTC<- as.POSIXct(depth$ISO_UTC, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "US/Pacific")
```

Please help me to put these data into usable datetime values.

Please see the above details.

Comment: Your data looks like it's in "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" minute format, so asking it to look for a different format like "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M" won't work.

Comment: Please share some data. For example with `dput()` and show the expected output!

Comment: (To clarify, the `format` parameter is telling `as.Date` what format should be parsed, not what format to output; that will always be YYYY-MM-DD.)

Comment: `depth$ISO_UTC<- as.Date(depth$ISO_UTC, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`